# How add specifc string(ex: TODO) along with a comment character for a specifc mode?

Tags: comment, todo

Based on specific `mode`, by using a keybinding I want to add a `TODO` string that is preceded by an unique comment character. For example, (org-mode is exception since `**` does not stands for comment and TODO shouldn't followed by `:`)

- `python-mode:` => `# TODO:`
- for script-mode: => `# TODO:`
- for latex mode: => `% TODO:`
- for org-mode: => `** TODO`

Basically comment character of the current mode on the buffer followed by `TODO:` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should cover the first cases (comment delimiter followed by " TODO: ")

```lisp
(defun insert-todo ()
  (interactive "*")
  (insert comment-start " TODO: "))
```

This one covers the `org-mode` case:

```lisp
(defun org-insert-todo ()
  (interactive "*")
  (insert "** TODO "))
```

You could bind them to a key combination with something like this

```lisp
(define-key prog-mode-map (kbd "C-c t") #'insert-todo)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c t") #'org-insert-todo)
```

In case you're wondering, the `*` in the `interactive` form serves to signal an error when the user invokes the function in a read-only buffer (see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html)).

Comment: `org-mode-map` is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I've deleted the heads-up in the answer

Comment: is it possible to have `C-c C-t` instead as keybinding? I tried it but didn't work

Comment: @alper It's `(define-key prog-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-t") #'insert-todo)` but note that `C-c <letter>` keybindings are reserved for the user while `C-c C-t` might conflict with the major mode's bindings ([ref.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html)). That could be why it's not working for you.